# How I can use the HTTP headers to indicate in the Response that possibility?

Tags: http, caching, http-headers

Finally I accomplished to cache dynamic images, css, and javascript files using HTTP headers BUT I have a problem now:

I have specific dynamic images that are equal but has different URL's.

For example:

1. http://example.com/image/src/the-same-image.jpg
2. http://example.com/image/custom/src/the-same-image2.jpg

1 and 2 has the same file content but different URL. This is a problem now because the navigator assumes that the file are different and need to be cached (due to the URL), when the real cached file is only one.

I have the possibility to know if the file at the URL's are the same.

How I can use the headers to indicate in the Response that possibility, and the navigator will cache only one file?

Comment: The real question: Why do you have the same image in two places?

Comment: Because: 1. It's a possibility and 2. My project has an organization that requires that an image or css can be found from particular to the general (global) images.  (general: /images/default-icon.jpg) (particular: /images/mycategory/default-icon.jpg)

Comment: if (/images/mycategory/default-icon.jpg doesn't exists)
    use /images/default-icon.jpg

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible. If you want to have your file to be cached properly even on different browsers they need to have the same URL.

Alternatively you could only think of a HTTP redirect 301 or 307.

But in any case you will have to think how you will keep checking if the files remain identical.

Answer (score 0):

Use redirect on your server. Redirect to the first URL if second URL is hit

Answer (score 0):

Different URIs are assumed to identify different resources. So both would be cached separately.

If you want to express that a resource is actually identified by a different URI, use an appropriate [HTTP redirection](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-10.3).